# how to display items in one row in boxed style view in sharepoint 2013

Tags: list-view

[image]

Is it possible to display all items in one row using the boxed style for SharePoint 2013?

The images below contains two row. How can I change it so all the content is on one row?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it display in one column , but i need in one row

Comment: So the name should be to the right of the image?

Comment: no all the images are right of the image

Comment: So you want all the images in one vertical row and the title in another? Can you cut, copy and paste how you would like it to look using paint and show us?

Comment: just now iam uploadsd  one image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have more then 2 boxes per row, open up the site in SharePoint Designer.

Find the list you wanna edit in SPD, and click on it. From `Views` on the top right side, click on the boxed listview (may be Allitems.aspx or if you created an additional view called something else).

Then from the top ribbon in SPD, select `Design`. From Actions, click on `Customize XSLT` and select `Customize entire view`.

Find the row `<xsl:when test="$Position mod 2 = 0">` and change it to `<xsl:when test="$Position mod 4 = 0">`.

Save in SPD and refresh the SharePoint page in the browser where the list exists. Now it should be 4 boxes per row.

This is the result.

[image]

Update: To set the width so it display correctly, add a `Script Editor WebPart` to the page and add this CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
table.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td.ms-stylebox {
width: 23,5%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it possible to set fixed width for the box , iam chaged the xsl , the boxes not have fixed with . iam uploaded the image .

Comment: once again thank you , i am searching for answer so many blogs but i can't  find . here iam find solution @user19952

Comment: @ranjith See my updated answer.

Comment: ThankYou @user19952

Comment: You can mark it as an answer if you wanna close the question. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to adjust the  that contains the column filters at the header of the table.  The original 3 span accommodates the 2 columns and a centre spacer column, so this needs to be adjusted upwards to accommodate how many columns in the box view you are adding plus the spacers between.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
 table.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td.ms-stylebox {
   width: 23.5% !important;
 }
 .ms-viewheadertr { display:none; }
</style>
```

Header columns filters mess the style arrangement, you should to hide them in order to fix and use the previous solution.

Thank you