# CSS Script for Multiple Columns Boxed Style

Tags: list-view

Using Sharepoint 2013,

List with Boxed Style. Looking for script to include in script editor to change the columns from two to three.

Comment: I've answered a questions similar to this one a couple of weeks ago. My answer requires some changes with SharePoint Designer and some CSS. Take a look here. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166547/how-to-display-items-in-one-row-in-boxed-style-view-in-sharepoint-2013/166553#166553

Answer (score 0):

- Open the view in Sharepoint designer
- Locate the "List view tools" bar and select "Design".
- Click "Customize XSLT" then select "Customize entire view"
- Find this line of code

  xsl:when test="$Position mod 2 = 0"

  and update it as you need. 
  For instance: If you need to display 4 columns instate of 2 then, replace the line of code by the following:

xsl:when test="$Position mod 4 = 0"