# Create more columns with SharePoint Online List

Tags: list-view, style

I am trying to create more than 2 columns views on the boxed style for the list a created. I tried following the steps here: [how to display items in one row in boxed style view in sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166547/how-to-display-items-in-one-row-in-boxed-style-view-in-sharepoint-2013/166553#166553?newreg=739ae13e077941ed96876ae6d036f707)

But using SharePoint Online via Office 365, and SharePoint Designer 2013, I don't see the options they mention.

Has there been an update or change that is required to allow this to work with my environment? Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online has a new user interface (the "modern UI") that, so far, does not include View Styles. You will only see them and their options when the list is displayed in the "Classic UI". You should see a link at the bottom of the Quick Launch area (left navigation) labeled "Return to Classic SharePoint".